# Does the Task Parallel Library provide a way to pool open connections?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, dynamics-crm-2011

### Background

I have a service that is connecting to Microsoft CRM 2011, and updating tens of thousands of records.  Running it single threaded results in only 30 records getting updated in a minute in  our dev environment.  I switched to multi-threading using TPL Parallel.Inovke, but the connection to CRM is not thread safe, and so I was creating a new connection for each record I was processing.  This change only increased my through put to 60 records per minute.  I then went back and batched the records together, so each thread would open one connection, and then process 1000 records at a time.  This increased my through put to around 500 updates a minute.  I could continue down this path and try to fine tune the size of my batch with the number of threads, but the real solution is to perform some sort of connection pooling, so every thread has it's own connection.

### How to Perform the Connection Pooling?

Does TPL provide a way of passing objects from an Action that is finishing to the next Action that is going to be processed?  If not, is there a good example somewhere of how to write your own connection pooling class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is nothing like this in TPL, it's not its job to provide connection pooling.

But one way to do this would be to use [one of the overloads of `Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx), that supports thread-local initialization.

Comment: So create the connection in the thread initialization?  How do I manage the scope to that connection?  Once the action has completed, will the thread just process the next action, or will a new thread get created?

Comment: Once one action has completed, another one is started on the same thread, with the same connection.